# What treats are dangerous for me to feed my cat?

Tags: cats, health, feeding, diet, treats

Considering [Is chocolate harmful for dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/781/can-chocolate-really-harm-my-dog) , are there foods which can endanger my cat?

---

Some relevant answers could be found here:

[Is it safe for my dog or cat to eat grapes, raisins and sultanas?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/802/is-it-safe-for-my-dog-or-cat-to-eat-grapes-raisins-and-sultanas)
[Is it OK to feed my dog or cat candy with sugar substitutes?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/798/is-it-ok-to-feed-my-dog-or-cat-candy-with-sugar-substitutes)
[Are onions dangerous for my cat or dog and why?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/796/why-are-onions-dangerous-for-my-cat-or-dog)
[Should I worry if my cat accidentally ate some chocolate?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-i-worry-if-my-cat-accidentally-ate-some-chocolate)
[What happens if cats drink coffee?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/what-happens-if-cats-drink-coffee)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When deciding on treats for your cat, remember that they are obligate carnivores and shouldn't be eating much other than meat. If you want to give your cat treats, try to look for freeze dried raw meats like beef liver and chicken. These are usually cheap and my cat loves them.

Any vegetables, dairy, candy and the like should be avoided, and probably never fed to your cat.

[This article](http://cats.about.com/cs/catfood/a/humanfood.htm) lists many of the foods you should not give your cat. There are many other sources available through [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=dangerous%20cat%20treats&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=harmful%20cat%20foods&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&safe=active).

A common misconception about cats is that milk is good for them. [Milk should not be given to your cat.](http://pets.webmd.com/cats/guide/cats-and-dairy-get-the-facts)

> Just like people, cats can be lactose intolerant. And although we tend to think that’s a problem, it’s actually completely normal

I realized that there is a similar answer about milk [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/780/should-i-feed-my-cat-milk).

Answer (score 6):

While this may sound odd, I had a cat that was addicted to coffee. She would hang around my feet in the morning while I made the daily brew, hoping for me to make a mistake and spill some beans or grounds. I gave in every now and then and would allow half a bean to drop, but decided to ask her vet if this should be allowed as she got older.

It appears that cats are more sensitive to caffeine than humans, and while the amount that I was allowing was "acceptable" any more should be considered dangerous.

Something to keep in mind if you ever find yourself with a feline that has acquired a taste for the oils in the coffee beans.

Comment: Cats can adore some strange things, @Coronus! One of our three positively adores ice cream. Not milk, not cream, just ice cream. His treat is to sometimes get to "clean" the ice cream container after we've emptied it - we get those little individual serve Haagen-Dasz for ourselves occasionally