# Cat may have consumed some garlic - will he be alright?

Tags: cats, diet, safety, poison

My flatmate left some garlic butter out and I think I just caught my cat licking it.

He probably had about 3 "licks".

Is that a toxic amount? He is almost a year old.

Comment: Related question that mentions garlic in the answer [Are onions dangerous for my cat or dog and why?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/796/are-onions-dangerous-for-my-cat-or-dog-and-why)

Comment: How was the garlic butter made do you know? Powdered garlic sources are typically much more concentrated than fresh.

Comment: @JohnCavan it was made from fresh garlic so that's a relief. He is fine:)

Answer (score 10):

[It takes less than 1g of garlic per kg of body weight to harm a cat](https://thepetauthority.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/how-much-onion-or-garlic-is-toxic-to-pets/) (it's about 5 times as potent as onion, which is a problem past 5g per kg).  Your cat's 3 licks shouldn't have been enough -- you didn't say how much your cat weighed, but to be safe, I've set your cat's weight to be 8 lbs (~3.6 kg) for this.  Your cat would have needed to ingest .008 lb of garlic, [about 1 supermarket clove's worth](http://www.greyduckgarlic.com/Garlic_Cooking_Tips.html).  While dips are often more concentrated than standard, three licks shouldn't be a problem. If your cat seems lethargic and gets white gums in a few days, however, I'd take it to the vet.

Comment: Thank you @Axelrod, he is perfectly fine. Great to have a formula though, thanks.