# How can I safely induce vomiting in a dog?

Tags: dogs, safety, eating, poison

[This answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/18016/224) says that salt is considered poisonous to dogs. Additionally, [the site linked](http://www.petpoisonhelpline.com/poison/salt/) in that answer states:

> The use of salt to induce vomiting in dogs and cats is no longer the
>   standard of care and is not recommended for use by pet owners or
>   veterinarians!

If I catch my dog eating something poisonous (like chocolate), how can I induce vomiting?

I would then take my dog to the vet, but it's over 30 minutes to the ER vet from my house, and I think it's better to get the chocolate out quickly than let him digest it for 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I have been instructed to make a dog vomit is to make it drink hydrogen peroxide.

Experience: Our Mountain Cur swallowed a fabric toy that he was chewing. We called the Vet and they said to induce vomiting by having him ingest Hydrogen Peroxide. While we were not successful in administering it to our dog as he is stubborn the Vet did say we could of held the dogs head and poured a little (2-3 cap full) in at 15 minuet intervals until he vomited. Also we could of used a plastic syringe/Dropper to get the liquid in his mouth.

Warning: Always consult your Vet prior to trying this to see if it is the right course of action. We called and spoke to our vet prior to doing this. And while we were unsuccessful it was not due to the hydrogen peroxide not working it was due to our dog not drinking it.