# What treats are safe for my ferrets to eat?

Tags: diet, ferrets, treats

I've read that ferrets can have small quantities of fruit, veggies, yogurt treats, and similar things you'd find labeled as "For ferrets". Are these actually safe for my ferret? Aren't they carnivores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ferrets, like cats, are obligate carnivores and should not eat much else other than meat! It's best to avoid grains, fruits, vegetables.. anything that's not meat. Treats like [Marshall Bandit Ferret Treats](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002AROQG) contain wheat flour and shouldn't be fed to your ferret.

Even occasionally feeding your ferret these sugary snacks has the potential to cause [Insulinomas](http://www.2ndchance.info/insulinoma.htm) which are essentially tumors of the pancreas caused by an insulin imbalance. It's expensive to treat and makes life much harder and more painful for your little one.

> Insulinoma is primarily a metabolic disease not a cancerous disease. It occurs because of the way the ferret’s body utilizes the nutrients in its diet to maintain its body. The most important step you can take to try to prevent this condition is to feed your pet a high quality, meat/poultry-based diet with as few additional plant ingredients as possible. Ferrets are very little animals. So even a few high-carbohydrate snacks and treats are significant.

If you want to give your ferrets treats, as I suggested in the other [question about cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/787/what-treats-are-dangerous-for-me-to-feed-my-cat/791#791), look for freeze-dried raw meats like beef liver, chicken, and turkey. Read the ingredients label and make sure that the meat is the ONLY ingredient in it. Treats like these are usually available at most chain pet stores. Things that contain grains (wheat/rice) should never be given to your ferret.