# What are safe plants to let my cat chew on?

Tags: cats, feeding

Someone mentioned in an comment about my cat and his love of string that I should give him something else to chew on. They suggested oat grass, but are there other types of things I can let him eat?

If possible, I'd like to make a "cat garden" in my window, a sort of salad buffet of sorts I can offer to my cat. What sorts of plants are safe?

Answer (score 2):

Grass, grass, grass, grass.

They tend to chew it to help vomiting hairballs. It is because the rough surface of the blades of grass irritates their stomach, which causes them to vomit. They have a natural instinct to eat grass.

Comment: Like normal every day outside grass?

Comment: @AshleyNunn Google "Cat Grass" there are a bunch of options, I think oat grass is popular because it grows quick.

Comment: outside grass works too.

Answer (score 2):

Hunter finds our ponytail palm fascinating (the leaves are bouncy). He hasn't been able to harm it (he doesn't have teeth) and it's nontoxic (I checked), but I'm not sure what a cat with teeth would do to one.

When we had Kendall, he loved to bat at it, but he didn't chew it.

I trim the frayed edges once a month or so, but my mom has one and she has to do the same thing, so I'm not sure how much of that is natural and how much is due to the cats.

Answer (score 0):

Remember cats are **obligate carnivores** and they shouldn't be eating anything that's not meat.

Check out [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/787/what-treats-are-dangerous-for-me-to-feed-my-cat/791#791) for reference.

If your cat is vomiting things back up, he shouldn't be eating it and that is a sign you should stop immediately.

If your cat needs treats, freeze dried meat treats are great in moderation. Otherwise, don't give them anything to eat that isn't food.

Comment: This goes against a lot of the other advice I have been given - I know he is an obligate carnivore. I am not trying to make him into a vegetarian or anything, but if you look at most cat foods, you are going to see they aren't 100% meat, for one thing.

Comment: I think I'm a bit of an extremist when it comes to feeding my cat (all raw meat, no treats save for the freeze dried ones, inside cat) which isn't the most popular opinion here. I don't worry about hairballs and MAYBE it's the diet? I dunno. I think it's a factor. 

Some of the vegetables in most cat foods probably helps move things along; but I don't think it would be necessary with a higher quality diet. It isn't an issue for me. Everything else (grain?) is filler and not necessary.

Comment: Entirely possible :) I know it isn't necessary, but also, for me at least, it is a function of cost - I cannot afford an entirely meat diet for my cat, but I do the best I can under my circumstances.

Comment: This is better as a comment than an answer I think. It doesn't really answer the question that was actually asked.

Answer (score -1):

"Cat Mint", as they call it in the UK. Standard lawn grass is poisonous to cats (which is why they eat it, to make themselves vomit for various reasons). Cat Mint is a grass with a mild psychedelic property for felines, meaning they don't vomit and they only eat a little. They love it.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're saying here.. You say "Cat Mint" is a grass that is poisonous to cats and they eat it to puke. Your second sentence says that felines don't puke when they eat. Which is it?

Comment: I suspect if they eat large amounts they throw up, perhaps?