# What should I do if my chihuahua licked some chocolate?

Tags: dogs, health, safety, eating

My chihuahua licked some chocolate from a 41g dark chocolate bar. She licked/ate a really small amount and though I can't tell how many grams it was, it seems that it should have been less than 5 grams?

She's really small, weighs less than 2 kilos and it was about an hour ago.

**Should I worried or take her to vet?**

Comment: Be aware that this is a question and answer site, that may not provide an answer in a timely fashion. This sounds like a medical emergency and you should contact your vet for specific instructions. If you don't receive an answer, in a few days, you may be the most knowledgeable person on the subject. Please return and post an answer to help others in the future.

Comment: We have a related question [Is chocolate harmful for dogs?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/781/is-chocolate-harmful-for-dogs) with an answer that says chocolate is potentially fatal, but does not include information about what dosage is problematic but the link in the answer does provide that information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a website that calculates the risk: [PetMD Chocolate Toxicity Meter](http://www.petmd.com/dog/chocolate-toxicity) According to this, a 4 lb. dog that ingested 0.2 oz of dark chocolate will have very mild symptoms, and you should keep an eye on him/her for GI upset, vomiting, or shaking. More serious indications would be tremors, seizures, hyperactivity, or racing heartbeat. (Note that I rounded down on weight and up on amount ingested when converting to U.S. units to see worst case). So you are probably OK, and I would guess that any symptoms would have shown up by now.

Comment: and remember that vomiting and diarrhea for a short while would actually be a good thing as it'd help purge the body of the toxins in the intestinal tract. Do keep the animal hydrated of course.